# How do I aggregate a table by multiple values as columns provided as values in a related table?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table of users like this:

```
Table user

id | name  | date
1  | alice | 2021-03-28
2  | bob   | 2021-03-29
...
```

And a table with their contacts:

```
Table contact

id | user_id | contact  | has_profile
1  | 1       | facebook | 1
2  | 1       | gmail    | 1
3  | 1       | yahoo    | 0
4  | 2       | facebook | 0
5  | 2       | gmail    | 1
6  | 2       | yahoo    | 1
...
```

I want to write a query that aggregates average rates of the contacts in different dates, so that the result should be:

```
date       | facebook | gmail | yahoo
2021-03-29 | 0.7      | 0.82  | 0.15
2021-03-28 | 0.75     | 0.85  | 0.18
...
```

I could reach it by the query:

```
select
    u."date",
    avg(f.has_profile) as facebook,
    avg(g.has_profile) as gmail,
    avg(y.has_profile) as yahoo
from user u
join contact f on f.user_id = u.id and f.contact = 'facebook'
join contact g on g.user_id = u.id and g.contact = 'gmail'
join contact y on y.user_id = u.id and y.contact = 'yahoo'
group by u."date"
order by u."date" desc
```

But the point is that this query depends on the certain contact names in the table `contact`, so if there are too many ones, the query is too long and complicated to modify. Is there a way to say to Postgresql to extract the names of the contacts automatically and to aggregate over them?

Comment: No. There's no way to dynamically pivot your date (create a dynamic number of columns)

Comment: @S-Man Maybe it is possible to pack the columns into a JSON field as keys? It would resolve my issue.

Comment: Yes that might work. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(JSON aggregate as requested in the comments)

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3224e9d2aa155a6961efc975280f55a7)

```
SELECT
    my_date,
    jsonb_object_agg(contact, avg)         -- 3
FROM (
    SELECT
        my_date,
        contact,
        AVG(has_profile)                   -- 2
    FROM
        contact c
    JOIN users u ON c.user_id = u.id       -- 1
    GROUP BY my_date, contact
) s
GROUP BY my_date
```

1. Join tables
2. Calculate average values by `date` and `contact`
3. Aggregate these values into a JSON object

**Unrelated note**: `date` and `user` are unrecommended names for database entities because they are reserved keywords. You have to handle them carefully (always use `"` characters). It's better to rename these properly. Moreover, date is not very descriptive. Maybe `login_date` or something

Comment: Thank you for the solution.